# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'past' when installing tensorboard with pytorch 1.2

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pytorch, tensorboard

I'm trying out tensorboard with pytorch by following this: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html

I've installed tensorboard with `pip install tb-nightly`

The command `tensorboard --logdir=runs` starts ok.

But the line `self.writer = SummaryWriter()`

Gives the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'past'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 26):

Following this issue: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/22389,

Adding `future` to the list of requirements solved the problem

```
# requirements.txt:
tb-nightly
future
```

`pip install -r requirements.txt`